# Selenium + Chrome WebDriver doesn't return page_source

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to adapt a webscraping script for Semantic Scholar using selenium. This part of the code works as expected, opening the website, typing in the title in the search bar and pressing enter

```
def _search_paper_by_name(self, paper_title: str) -> None:
    """
    Go to the search page for 'paper_name'.
    """

    self._web_driver.get(self._site_url)
    self._wait_element_by_name('q') 

    input_search_box = self._web_driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    input_search_box.send_keys(paper_title)
    input_search_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

However, if at any point I try printing the page's code, the code stops working as expected (Does not type anything on search bar), and no HTML is printed:

```
def _search_paper_by_name(self, paper_title: str) -> None:
    """
    Go to the search page for 'paper_name'.
    """

    self._web_driver.get(self._site_url)
    self._wait_element_by_name('q') 
    print(self._web_driver.page_source)

    input_search_box = self._web_driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    input_search_box.send_keys(paper_title)
    input_search_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

I'm confused and I don't understand why I'm not able to print the source code and why does the print statement mess up the rest of the code.

EDIT: As requested

I have a SemanticScraper object. the web_driver gets initialized as None when the object is created:

def **init**(self, timeout=5, time_between_api_call=0.5, headless=True,
site_url='https://www.semanticscholar.org/'):
"""
:param timeout: Number of seconds the web driver should wait before raising a timeout error.
:param time_between_api_call: Time in seconds between api calls.
:param headless: If set to be true, the web driver launches a browser (chrome) in silent mode.
:param site_url: Home for semantic scholar search engine.
"""

```
    self._site_url = site_url
    self._web_driver = None
    self._timeout = timeout
    self._time_between_api_call = time_between_api_call
    self._headless = headless
```

And then whenever the scraper makes a search, it opens the browser like this:

```
def _start_browser(self):
    chrome_options = Options()
    if self._headless:
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

    self._web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: Can you add the code where `self._web_driver` is defined?

Comment: What is the error that u get when u run this code?

Comment: Added the requested code! Thank you.

I don't get any error, it just stops working as intended